# SQLAlchemy parameter creation by loop or function

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm building a short answer quiz (input as a string).  While I've managed to get the quiz up and running, I'm finding that I'm writing code which seems to be a) a bit ugly/unwieldy and b) isn't expandable/reusable in different situations.

Here's an example (this pattern is used a number of times in different functions):

```
answers_to_store = Answer(answer_1=user_answer_list[0],
                              answer_2=user_answer_list[1],
                              answer_3=user_answer_list[2],
                              answer_4=user_answer_list[3],
                              answer_5=user_answer_list[4])
```

Is there a better way to create these parameters?  I can't see a way of replacing the parameter name (i.e. answer_1) with a variable or similar (which is the only way I can think of making the task easier).

The only way I've found would be to create the parameters as text using a loop, and then running the resulting command via exec - is that the only way of achieving this, or is there a better way?  The other limitation is that this means that having a storage function to store 5 answers from a quiz would be different to one storing 20 answers (the database has that many columns).

I've tried searching, but the problem is I don't know the right term for this, and the nearest thing I came up with was the creation of the appropriate command via a loop and exec - which would work, but seems a long-winded way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a short answer quiz, create a database of questionID,  answer_string then access the table with the questionID and compare the output with the user input. Here is the idea:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, MetaData, Column, Integer, VARCHAR
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker

Session = sessionmaker()

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db')
Session.configure(bind=engine)

sess = Session()

metadata = MetaData()

question = Table('question', metadata,
             Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
             Column('answerKey', VARCHAR(None))
             )

class Question(object):
    def __init__(self, answer):
        self.answer = answer


mapper(Question, question)


def check(INquestionID, answerInput):
    # Return an answer string associated with the question.
    ans = sess.query(question.answer).filter(question.id == INquestionID).limit(1)

    if answerInput == ans[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This method stores a string (up to 8000 characters in SQL Server), accesses based on the ID and compares for grading.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for that, unfortunately it's not a multiple-choice quiz, each question has a string as an answer, so I still can't see how to access/create the parameters in a neat manner.

Comment: @djaychela string input is a pretty important part of the quiz. i've suggested an edit.

Comment: Also, you should notice that I've edited the answer to accommodate the answer string.